# Recursive Merge Sort - Stack Overflow Error

Tags: java, recursion, merge, stack-overflow

I'm doing a school project where I have to write a program that performs a merge sort. The `mergeSort()` method is recursive and is causing a stack overflow error. I know that this happens if a recursive method continues endlessly, but I can't figure out what in my code is making it not stop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code (it's run with a `Sort.java` program provided by my professor, if that clarifies why there is no `main` method):

```
public class Merge {

    /**
     * Sort an array, in-place, using merging.
     * @param array The array to be sorted.
     * POSTCONDITION: The elements of array are in ascending order.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array) {

        int[] tempArray = mergeSort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            array[i] = tempArray[i];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Extract the portion of an array from start up to (excluding) stop.
     * @param array The source array.
     * @param start The starting index (inclusive).
     * @param stop  The ending index (exclusive).
     * @return An array containing the same elements the portion of array.
     * PRECONDITION: 0 <= start <= stop <= array.length
     */
    private static int[] subarray(int[] array, int start, int stop) {

        int[] newArray = new int[stop-start];
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = array[start + i];
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    /**
     * Merge two sorted arrays into one new array.
     * @param first The first array, already sorted.
     * @param second The second array, already sorted.
     * @return A new array containing the elements of first and second,
     *         in order.
     */
    private static int[] merge(int[] first, int[] second) {

        int[] newArray = new int[first.length + second.length]; 
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while ((i < first.length) || (j < second.length)) {
            if ((i < first.length) && (j < second.length)) {
                if (first[i] < second[j]) {
                    newArray[count++] = first[i++];
                } else { 
                    newArray[count++] = second[j++];
                }
            } else if (j < second.length) {
                newArray[count++] = second[j++]; 
            } else if (i < first.length) { 
                newArray[count++] = first[i++];
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    /**
     * Sort an array by merging.
     * @param array The array to sort.
     * @return A new array containing the elements of array, in order.
     */
    private static int[] mergeSort(int[] array) {
        int split = 0;
        if (array.length < 2) {
            return array;
        } else {
            split = array.length%2;
            int[] array1 = mergeSort(subarray(array, 0, split));
            int[] array2 = mergeSort(subarray(array, split, array.length));
            return merge(array1, array2);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually, there is a reason why JavaScript bears its name.  There originally _was_ a relation between Java and JavaScript; the latter was intended to be used to control Java applets running in early web pages.  But yeah, for sure they're not the same language.

Comment: This is a good time for you to learn how to use a debugger.  Get into your code, line by line, and see what is happening.  Start with small input arrays, say of size 4 or less.  So my answer is: use a debugger.

Comment: one thing: the implementations of mergesort i checked all don't modulo `split = array.length%2;` but `split = array.length/2;` as pointed out by a user who just deleted his comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `split = array.length%2;` is supposed to be `split = array.length/2;`

It's going to take a while if the array has an even length, since the second subarray will effectively be equal to the original array, and you get infinite recursion. With an odd-length array, the second subarray will be even-length, and you again get infinite recursion.

---

To debug infinite recursion, first use `printf` statements to check what's going on *just before you recurse* (since that'll probably be where things go wrong) to make sure the recursion is going as planned, like:

```java
split = array.length%2;
System.err.printf(
    "%d broken into %d (%d to just before %d) and %d (%d to just before %d).\n",
    array.length, split, 0, split, array.length - split, split, array.length);
int[] array1 = mergeSort(subarray(array, 0, split));
int[] array2 = mergeSort(subarray(array, split, array.length));
return merge(array1, array2);
```

See if things are getting smaller in the ways that they should.